# CSV output is empty

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am one step before finishing a project. As far as I know, all parts of the code works, and I have tested them separately. However, the output CSV still comes out empty for some reason. My code:

```
import requests, bs4, csv, sys

reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

url = 'http://www.constructeursdefrance.com/resultat/?dpt=01'
count = 1

def result():
    res = requests.get(url)
    res.raise_for_status()
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,'html.parser')
    links = []
    try:    
        for div in soup.select('.link'):
            link = div.a.get('href')
            links.append(link)

        with open('french.csv', 'wb') as file:
            writer = csv.writer(file)
            for i in links:
                res2 = requests.get(i)
                soup2 = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res2.text, 'html.parser')
                for each in soup2.select('li > strong'):
                    writer.writerow([each.text, each.next_sibling])

    except:
        pass

while not url.endswith('?dpt=010'):
    print 'downloading %s' %url
    result()
    count += 1
    url = 'http://www.constructeursdefrance.com/resultat/?dpt=0' +    str(count)

url = 'http://www.constructeursdefrance.com/resultat/?dpt=10'
count = 10
while not url.endswith('?dpt=102'):
    print 'downloading %s' %url
    result()
    count += 1
    url = 'http://www.constructeursdefrance.com/resultat/?dpt=' + str(count)

print 'done'
```

This is really one of the first bigger projects I am trying to solve as a beginner. Being so close yet so stuck is frustrating, however. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm guessing you have an exception in your try block, and the except: pass doesn't tell you what it is. Never use except: pass if the exceptions are important to the logic of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, do not use try except in a large block, just use in a small place.
if you comment of you try except statement, this error will raise:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/li/PycharmProjects/tw/1.py", line 29, in <module>
    result()
  File "/home/li/PycharmProjects/tw/1.py", line 26, in result
    writer.writerow([each.text, each.next_sibling])
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

and this error message is clear, when it write to file, it require a bytes_like object, and you can check that the file you opened is in 'wb' mode, 'b' represent bytes mode, so the problem is clear, just change the mode to normal mode which require a str_like object:

```
with open('french.csv', 'w') as file:
```